# Having problems implementing navigation drawer in android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer for my app that I'm trying to create. I fairly new android studio and I had this idea of implementing navigation drawer in the app. Everything works fine until I write the code for the navigation drawer and the app crashes.

When I try to click on the hamburger icon in the top left corner of the screen the app crashes. I can't figure out where is the problem occurring. I would really appreciate if someone helps me out here. Been stuck for almost two days now. I've been looking for youtube tutorials all over the internet followed quite a few of them, but none of them worked out. Even took help of chatGPT but still can't figure out the error. I'm providing the files for my app below.

Below is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="#EEE3CB"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:background="#F9E0BB"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Discrete Math Topics"
                android:textSize="28dp"
                />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="603dp"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/adView">

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Logic" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Sets" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter4" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter5" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter6" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter7" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter8" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter9" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter10" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter11" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter12" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn13"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter13" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn14"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Chapter14" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn15"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:text="Chapter15" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn16"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:text="Chapter16" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5886553399470613/3766483794"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.mathprojectraoli;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.AdapterStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(@NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        String[] activityNames = {
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter1",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter2",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter3",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter4",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter5",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter6",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter7",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter8",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter9",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter10",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter11",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter12",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter13",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter14",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter15",
            "com.example.mathprojectraoli.Chapter16"};
        Button buttons[] = {
                findViewById(R.id.btn1),
                findViewById(R.id.btn2),
                findViewById(R.id.btn3),
                findViewById(R.id.btn4),
                findViewById(R.id.btn5),
                findViewById(R.id.btn6),
                findViewById(R.id.btn7),
                findViewById(R.id.btn8),
                findViewById(R.id.btn9),
                findViewById(R.id.btn10),
                findViewById(R.id.btn11),
                findViewById(R.id.btn12),
                findViewById(R.id.btn13),
                findViewById(R.id.btn14),
                findViewById(R.id.btn15),
                findViewById(R.id.btn16)};

        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        {
            final String activityName = activityNames[i];
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName(activityName));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my main_menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
            android:title="Home"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/AboutUs"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_about_us_24"
            android:title="About Us"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/Contacts"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_contacts_24"
            android:title="Contacts"/>
    </group>
    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item android:id="@+id/Share"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"
                    android:title="Share"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/Rate"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_rate_review_24"
                    android:title="Rate this App"/>
                <item android:id="@+id/Feedback"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                    android:title="Send Feedback"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Here is my menu_header.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#213555"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/discrete_math_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discrete Mathematics"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the strings.xml file

```
<resources>
    <string name="main_menu">Main Menu</string>
    <string name="chap1">Chapter 1</string>
    <string name="chap2">Chapter2</string>
    <string name="chap3">Chapter3</string>
    <string name="chap4">Chapter4</string>
    <string name="chap5">Chapter5</string>
    <string name="chap6">Chapter6</string>
    <string name="chap7">Chapter7</string>
    <string name="chap8">Chapter8</string>
    <string name="chap9">Chapter9</string>
    <string name="chap10">Chapter10</string>
    <string name="chap11">Chapter11</string>
    <string name="chap12">Chapter12</string>
    <string name="chap13">Chapter13</string>
    <string name="chap14">Chapter14</string>
    <string name="chap15">Chapter15</string>
    <string name="chap16">Chapter16</string>
    <string name="mathprojectraoli">mathprojectraoli</string>
    <string name="open">Open Navigation Drawer</string>
    <string name="close">Close Navigation Drawer</string>

</resources>
```

Logcat error that I'm receiving.

```
2023-06-07 17:17:04.201 3656-3719/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.mathprojectraoli/app_webview/variations_seed": /data/user/0/com.example.mathprojectraoli/app_webview/variations_seed (No such file or directory)
2023-06-07 17:17:05.000 3656-3755/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2023-06-07 17:17:06.622 3656-3755/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2023-06-07 17:17:12.623 3656-3656/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mathprojectraoli, PID: 3656
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(112896000bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:5030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:4429)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.dispatchDraw(NavigationView.java:501)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.draw(ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java:109)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1478)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
2023-06-07 17:17:12.623 3656-3656/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Just for more references about what I mean by my error I am providing some screenshots below.

[This is the main layout of my app. That is the main screen window when a user opens the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMs4e.png)

[But when I click the hamburger menu at the top left corner the app shows me this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l6Rw.png)

It would be a great deal of help if someone helps me out here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you copy the error you receive in the Logcat?

Comment: I just now edited the post and uploaded the logcat error too.

Comment: used image or icon graphics is too high to load in application

Answer (score 0):

Add This line in manifest application tag and try.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Supposed to be it will not work then add this tag too.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: Wow it worked. I added the code android:hardwareAccelerated="false" and android:largeHeap="true" and it worked. Thank you so much. I can't believe it finally worked out.

Comment: It might work, but you load a image which has a size of more than 100 MB into your view. That's really bad for the performance of your app. Keep this in mind.